# Where Can I Find Demo/Sample Code For Perl 6?

Tags: scripting, sample, raku, rakudo

I've got myself a copy of Rakudo and I'd love to give it a test drive. After looking around the Internet I found some code snippets of cool Perl 6 stuff, but no complete scripts. Any sites that make practical Perl 6 scripts available would be appreciated.

Thanks guys, Ehtyar.

Answer (score 11):

Please check out the perl6-examples repository from http://github.com/perl6/perl6-examples/tree/master, it contains many nice examples.

Also don't hesitate to join #perl6 or irc.freenode.net if you have any questions (or perl6-users@perl.org if you're more the email user).

Sometimes there are also very nice examples on the Perl 6 blogs out there, most of them are collected on http://pl6anet.org.

See also Perl 6 examples on [Rosetta Code](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Category:Perl_6).

Comment: Planetsix looks like a great blog to read once I become more familiar with perl 6, but I think it has too much content to sift through looking for examples. The github link is excellent, thanks for that :) #perl6 is one of the channels i auto-join whenever I'm on freenode, it's a great place to talk about perl 6.

Comment: The rest of Moritz's answer still stands but I'm sure he'd have also listed http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Category:Perl_6 if he'd been answering today (his answer is from 2009).

Answer (score 5):

[This page](http://www.perlfoundation.org/perl6/index.cgi?the_perl_6_language) at the Perl foundation covers new features very well. Specifically "The Long Perl 6 Super-Feature List" (Which isn't actually very long, it explains what new features will be coming in bullet points). If you are specifically looking for new features only, that is the place to look as opposed to sifting through mounds of sample code and dissecting new features.

There are some good smaller examples on [this](http://szabgab.com/talks/perl6/) page that will demonstrate new features without an elaborate amount of code.

Comment: I was about to suggest subscribing to Gabor's website and mailing list.

Comment: Hi John.

I was already aware of 'Learn about perl 6', but the perl 6 talks is an excellent link with a good number of examples. Thanks very much :)

Answer (score 4):

A great place for other perl6 stuff is the [Perlgeek](http://perlgeek.de/blog-en/perl-5-to-6/) blog; there are several articles and examples there, including a functional grammar for JSON parsing...very cool.

Answer (score 3):

As Robert mentioned, the [Perlgeek](http://perlgeek.de/blog-en/perl-5-to-6/) blog has some great articles.  I've written a [couple articles](http://mfollett.com/blog/categories/perl-6/) myself, but they mostly cover specific things of Perl 6 ([classes](http://mfollett.com/perl-6-coding-with-class), [methods](http://mfollett.com/27523143), etc).

You can look at the Using Perl 6 book, which is freely available as a pdf [here](http://www.github.com/perl6/book/downloads/).  It has lots of code examples for the concepts and features it covers.  The book is also available in the docs directory of the latest Rakudo * release.

Also, I'd recommend looking through the spec tests.  If you have Rakudo * installed they should be in rakudo/t/spec.  They are organized by the [synopsis](http://perlcabal.org/syn/), which can be a little confusing.  However, the benefit from looking through them is great, you'll get a chance to see multiple examples of how to use concepts in Perl 6 that you know work in your current build because you can run the test.

Answer (score 2):

Resources I think helpful at the time of writing this comment (June 2015), listed from most to least QA'd:

- [examples.perl6.org](http://examples.perl6.org).
- Short [one liners article](http://perltricks.com/article/136/2014/11/20/Get-started-with-Perl-6-one-liners).
- [Perl 6 advent calendars](https://perl6advent.wordpress.com/).
- [jnthn's talks](http://jnthn.net/articles.shtml) eg ["Perl 6: what can you do today?"](http://jnthn.net/papers/2014-fosdem-perl6-today.pdf). Good resource for examples of concurrency.
- Perl 6 entries at [Rosetta Code](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Category:Perl_6). Many of these are written by Larry Wall.
- Modules on [modules.perl6.org](http://modules.perl6.org).
- [Perl6Maven](http://perl6maven.com). Contains snippets and a long, incomplete, partly bitrotted P6 tutorial, but the site's owner (Gabor Szabgab) has said he intends to build out his P6 content this year (2015) so it's worth at least a quick visit.